# Seleium Can not lauch Chrome Browser on Apache via mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, selenium, mod-wsgi

I am developing a Django Project. I use a view named test_seleium_view() to lauch a Chrome Browser by Seleium. For demonstration purpose, my code is as simple as below:

urls.py

```
# coding=utf-8
from __future__ import unicode_literals, absolute_import
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [url(r'^test_seleium$',test_seleium_view,name='test_seleium'),]
```

test_seleium.py

```
# coding=utf-8
from __future__ import unicode_literals, absolute_import
import time
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from selenium import webdriver

def test_seleium_view(request):
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
    CHROME_DRIVER_PATH = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver\chromedriver_win32_v2.43.exe"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROME_DRIVER_PATH, chrome_options=chrome_options)

    driver.get('http://www.google.com')
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.quit()

    return render_to_response('result.html',{'text': "success"})
```

When I visit http://127.0.0.1:8000/app_name/test_seleium on Django development server, everything is working fine, Seleium lauch a Chrome browser then open http://www.google.com wait for 5 seconds then close Chrome browser.

Then I take this Django project to my virtual machine(VMware Workstation, win 7 64bit installed) which installed Apache and mod_wsgi, when I visit http://my_vmware_virtual_host_ip:8000/app_name/test_seleium, it doesn't lauch Chrome browser, but after a while, the page show the text "success",just like test_seleium_view() had ran successfully, and there is a chrome.exe process on windows 7 background.

my environment：

```
VMware Workstation 15.0.0 build-10134415
Windows 7 64bit on VMware Virtual Machine
Apache 2.4.37 Win64
mod_wsgi 4.6.5+ap24vc14-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64
python 3.6.4 64bit
Django 2.0.7
selenium 3.14.1
chromdriver win32_v2.43，win32_v2.42
```

I search this problem on google.com, but got little luck.

I found a similar question on [StackOverFlow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47756551/cannot-run-python-selenium-script-under-localhost), but it got no answer.

Comment: I am facing the same problem right now. Did you ever resolve?